# Toilet is leaking around the base

Tags: leak, toilet

Last Wednesday, my toilet experienced a small leak around the base. I monitored it for a few days and I didn't see the leak again. Today, the toilet leaked around the base again. This time, there was a lot of water on the floor. I cleaned up the area and have flushed several times since I noticed the leak and it's not leaking. What could this be?

Comment: Is the toilet base loose? The wax ring will fail if there's movement in the mounting. Also, do you have small children in the house?

Comment: The toilet base is not loose. No small children in the house.

Comment: Tank to bowl connection can mimic a base leak.

Answer (score 1):

Check your water supply connections and tighten them as needed, first.

After that, I would suspect and just plan on replacing the toilet's seal, either wax or wax-free are perfectly fine. This, is actually fairly easy and quick to do.

Sound like a leap? Well, doing so may reveal the seal to be the actual problem, but also force you to assess the entire toilet in wrestling it.

If you have a 2-piece toilet, the leak could be coming from failing bolt washers in the bottom of the tank or a failing tank to bowl gasket under the tank. Is your tank loose and wobbly? A good chance that the water's coming from the tank connections that need to be tightened.

A final item is the fill valve and even specifically the bowl filling tube. The valve may be spraying the tank lid or the bowl filler may have come loose and is spraying the lid.

Like above, water may be finding the toilet's exterior and just running down to the base periodically.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP with our new (1950s) house.  Took off the toilet since the subfloor needed to be replaced anyway, and lo and behold:  the wax ring was in perfect condition, and the bolts holding down the base hadn't been tightened even finger-tight.  I second the toilet removal.

Answer (score 0):

I had an American Standard toilet crack years after it was installed. I have only seen this 1 time. The crack was so smallI could not see it. A replacement toilet fixed the problem.